# mobx-react: component no response to injected store

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have an component and injected with a store instance:

```
import React from "react";
import { inject, observer } from "mobx-react";

import Retention from "./Retention";

@inject(() => {
  return {
    retentionStore: new Retention()
  };
})
@observer
export default class RetentionChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    const { setFlag } = this.props.retentionStore;
    setFlag(Math.random());
  }
  render() {
    const { retentionStore } = this.props;
    const { loading, error, result } = retentionStore;

    console.log(loading, error, result);
    return null;
  }
}
```

And here is the `Retention` store code:

```
import { observable, autorun, reaction, action, computed, flow } from "mobx";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Retention {
  @observable error = "";
  @observable loading = false;
  @observable result = null;

  @observable flag = false;

  @action
  setFlag = value => {
    this.flag = value;
  };

  query = flow(function*() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.error = "";
    try {
      this.result = yield axios
        .get("https://randomuser.me/api/")
        .then(response => {
          return response.data;
        });
    } catch (error) {}
    this.loading = false;
  });

  constructor() {
    reaction(
      () => this.flag,
      () => {
        this.query();
      }
    );
  }
}
```

What I want do is simple: when any props of the component changed, it lunch a query

However, when I put the component into an parent component, try to update the props of the child component, the query could lunched, but the child component no response to the observable change in the store:

```
import React from "react";
import { observer, inject } from "mobx-react";
import RetentionChart from "../RetentionChart";

export default class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      flag: false
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { flag } = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        onClick={() =>
          this.setState({
            flag: !this.state.flag
          })
        }
      >
        <p>Clickable</p>
        <RetentionChart flag={flag} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What's wrong with my code ? Why can't it response ? How can I fix it?

Here is the [jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9a0Lnf1u/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@inject(() => {
  return {
    retentionStore: new Retention()
  };
})
```

every time you got a new store. Try following code.

```
const retentionStore = new Retention();
@inject(() => ({retentionStore}))
```

Comment: I know `new` a store is not a best practice, but I still can't get what's wrong with it

Comment: @hh54188 the arrow function you passed in `inject` function return an object which is passed as props to RetentionChart. When you click the item, `query` function modify the variable in current store, then the component did update: it actually runs the `inject` function again, and pass a `new` store to RetentionChart, not the former one you passed. So all the variable in the store is in their initial state.